# How to put code snippets in Angular 5 *.component.html

Tags: angular, angular5

I am working on an Angular 5 project at the moment. I am facing a tricky issue here.

I want to include some code snippets in my component.html file, through the use of the `<code>` tag. But doing so seems to return an processing error on the angular side. So I tried to put the code in variable on the *.component.ts file, and using data binding, display the code like this:

```
<code_tag>{{my_code_snippet}}</code_tag>
```

But now the issue is that the code always comes out as a string, and not properly formatted (for example if it is JSON code)

How should I tackle this?

Comment: Have you tried <pre>{{my_code_snippet}}</pre> tag ?

Comment: did you try this [innerHTML]="my_code_snippet" on the code container?

Comment: Hi, I have added the <pre> tag an it seems to be working. Thanks. [InnerHTML] also works fine.

Comment: I have used the <pre> tag, it is not working even after that

Answer (score 1):

You can tell Angular to ignore strings in the `<code>` element with the  `ngNonBindable` attribute

```
<code ngNonBindable>
    console.log("no output");
</code>
```

Comment: You may still have issues displaying curly braces because of this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11859